# In C#, is it possible to restrict a class accessibility to the file defining it?

Tags: c#

I can't declare it as private in another class because I have several classes that use it. I also don't want it to be internal otherwise it will be exposed to other classes in the same assembly. I want it to be accessible just to the classes in the same file. Is it possible in C#?

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: nooooooo.

Comment: I don't understand why you need this behavior. Could you explain the scenario a little more? Maybe there is another, more conventional solution.

Comment: This is somewhat of an unusual requirement. It sounds like those classes "in the same file" should be in a separate assembly.

Answer (score 13):

There's very little in the C# language which is done at at the level of "source file".

The closest you could come would be to create a top-level class and have several nested classes:

```
class Foo
{
    internal class A
    {
        private Shared shared = new Shared();
    }

    internal class B
    {
        private Shared shared = new Shared();
    }

    private class Shared
    {
    }
}
```

It's not a very pleasant solution though, to be honest. If a class needs to be visible to a number of other classes, I'd typically prefer to make it internal and *either* extract out those classes to another assembly *or* live with the shared class being visible to other clsses in the same assembly which don't really need to know about it.

Comment: This is outdated, check Yusufs answer.

Answer (score 10):

It's possible with [file access modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/file) starting from C# 11.

> Beginning with C# 11, the file contextual keyword is a type modifier. 
>
> The file modifier restricts a top-level type's scope and visibility to the file in which it's declared. The file modifier will generally be applied to types written by a source generator. File-local types provide source generators with a convenient way to avoid name collisions among generated types. The file modifier declares a file-local type, as in this example:

```
file class HiddenWidget
{
    // implementation
}
```